# Is there any infection that targets/found in specifically the nape of the neck?

Tags: virus, bacteria, infectious-diseases, neck, fungal-infection

Is there any infection(s) of the nape caused by a foreign body (bacterial, viral, fungal, etc)? I mean a foreign body infection found or originating primarily or solely in the nape.

I know some ENT infections can spread to the neck but they don't originate in the neck (or the nape).

I also understand that trauma (cut or wound) to the nape can become infected or a keloid on the nape can become infected by bacteria. But as I understand, these bacteria don't have any more special affinity for the nape as they would for a wound anywhere else.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, **what made you ask this question**, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no infection "found or originating primarily or solely in the nape". Any skin infection (eg. Staphyloccus, Streptococcus) can affect the nape of the neck. Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! We work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.